# How can I create a subclass using django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

Hello I am using django with a postgre database and in my database I have 5 columns and one of them is called : "data" and in the data there is :

```
|data |
|{"name":"Peter","city":"New York"}|
|{"name":"Denis","city":"Paris"}|
|{"name":"Jennifer","city":"San Francisco"}|
|{"name":"Kim","city":"Berlin"}|
```

And I would like to extract this column and create a subtable by the name of dataExtract for instance such as :

```
|name|city|
|Peter|New York|
|Denis|Paris|
|Jennifer|San Francisco|
|Kim|Berlin|
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField

Comment: Why do you think you need either a subclass or a "subtable" for this? What do you actually want to *do* with that extracted data?

Comment: Actually it is because the queries are very slow ... With this substable it will be faster.

Comment: `subclass`/`subtable`(especially in case of postgres) are pretty specific terms. All you want is _another_ model, _another_ table (with FK, I suppose).

Comment: Are you just looking for the concept of a [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related)?

Comment: No actually I just have to do this because the queries are very low ...

Answer (score 0):

create a new model:

```
class DataExtract(Base):
    main = models.OneToOneField(
        MainModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=400, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=400, blank=True)
```

for populating ExtractData table with existing data in MainModel table, use this code just once:

```
for main in MainModel.object.all():
    ExtractData.create(name=main.data__name,city=main.data__city)
```

after initial populating of DataExtract table, now you have to use signal for inserting into DataExtract table after each insert into MainModel table like this:

```
class DataExtract(Base):
    ......
    ......

    @receiver(post_save, sender=MainModel)
        def create_data_extract(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
            # you have to check here for duplicate, 
            # if there is no duplicate, create it.
            # if there is duplicate update that
            ExtractData.create(name=instance.data__name,city=instance.data__city)
```